# What is correct way to flip coordinate on image?

Tags: image-processing

I got image dataset with landmarks on them to process augmentation. My question is how to correctly compute the flip landmarks on flip images?

I now have three ways below, and which one should be the correct one ?

```py
# flip left and right 
# 1
x2 = width - x1

# 2
x2 = width - 1 - x1  # 

# 3
x2 = width - 1 - math.floor(x1) + x1 - math.floor(x1)
```

Comment: Flip vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Both. But I think the computation method should be the same.